# Playing with dolls and Aisha

Tags: fiqh, sharia, islamic-scholar, usool-ul-fiqh, school

In this hadith, Aisha is said to play with dolls:

> A'ishah, may Allaah be pleased with her, narrated that she used to
> play with dolls in the presence of the Prophet, sallallaahu ʻalayhi wa
> sallam, and that her friends also used to play with her. When the
> Prophet, sallallaahu ʻalayhi wa sallam, would enter (her dwelling
> place), they used to hide, but the Prophet, sallallaahu ʻalayhi wa
> sallam, would call them to join and play with her. (Fath Al-Bari, page
> 143, Vol.13)

According to Al-Khattabi and Ibn Battal, this meant that Aisha didn't hit puberty, since dolls were considered idols:

> Ibn Battaal may Allaah have mercy upon him commented on this hadeeth,
> saying, “The hadeeth indicates that the toys that young girls play
> with are allowed, meaning dolls, which are essentially statues. We do
> not find an interpretation for this concession except that it is
> granted to young children for playing with.” [Sharh Saheeh Al-Bukhari]
>
> Al-Khattabi commented on this hadeeth, saying, ‘It is deduced from
> this hadeeth that playing with dolls is not like the amusement with
> other images concerning which the threat of punishment is mentioned.
> Rather, it was deemed permissible for ʻAa'ishah to play with these
> dolls because she had not yet reached puberty then.’ ([Source](https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/328036/meaning-of-hadeeth-about-aaishahs-playing-with-dolls))

Is this a general rule (playing with dolls is idol worship before puberty)? If so, please name the scholars. I have been told there are other scholars who claim that there was an exception for Aisha. Who are these scholars in question.

Comment: Where did you get "dolls were considered idols" from or where did you get any relation to idol-worship from?